# How to deprecate a function input argument and maintain backward compatibility

Tags: python, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I would like to change the input arguments of a function. This will also lead to changes within the function body.
What's a pythonic way to mark an input argument "deprecated" and maintain backward compatibility at the same time? Here's a toy example:

```
from typing import List


# original function
def sum_numbers(numbers: List[int]):
    return sum(numbers)


# function with changed input arguments and function body
def sum_numbers(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

The user should be able to call `sum_numbers` either with `numbers: List[int]` argument or by using `a: int, b: int`. However, I want to submit a `DeprecationWarning` when the user uses the original call method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to overload the function using `multipledispatch` module:

```py
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(int, int)
def sum_numbers(a, b):
    print("Deprecated")
    return a + b

@dispatch(list)
def sum_numbers(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `multipledispatch` is to take in `*args` or have an optional arg and dispatch internally:

```py
# original function
def sum_numbers(a, b=None):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        warnings.warn("...", DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
        return sum(numbers)
    return a + b
```

then for typing purposes you can use [typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.overload):

```py
@typing.overload
def sum_numbers(numbers: list[int]) -> int:
    """deprecated"""
@typing.overload
def sum_numbers(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    ...
```

(note that as documented the overloads should come first and the actual implementation last)